# Uploading file using Javascript and execute_script in Python Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, upload

I am trying to use Selenium to automatically add a file on [this](https://twitter.com/statuses/778637767198830592) twitter link .

I have found that I can do this by doing:

```
    # filePath is a proper path to an image
    uploadPhoto = driver.find_elements_by_name('media_empty')[1]
    uploadPhoto.send_keys(filePath)
```

However, I need to be able to do the same thing using Selenium's 'execute_script' command.  I have tried the following, but it's not working:

```
    uploadPhoto = driver.find_elements_by_name('media_empty')[1]
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].innerHTML=\'' + filePath + '\';', uploadPhoto)
```

Any ideas on how to add a photo the execute_script command and some JavaScript?

Comment: sorry but this link not work. It will give "page doesn’t exist" Error.

Comment: I changed the link to link to a new, valid tweet.

Comment: I can not see file upload control.can you give me direction where to upload file?

Comment: If you click inside of the text area to reply, some more icons appear at the bottom.  One of the icons is a camera for uploading photos.